# Activites sometimes are removed from NfcService

Tags: android, nfc

Activites sometimes are removed from NfcService.
How can I detect removing my activities from NfcService??
And how can I re-register my activities to NfcService??

▼My setting is below.

```
NfcAdapter m_NFC;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        if (m_NFC != null) {
            m_NFC.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
    return;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    m_NFC.enableForegroundDispatch(this,PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()), 0),null,null);
    return;
}
```

▼launchMode

```
android:launchMode="singleTask" or "singleTop"
```

▼Log is below...

```
09-13 15:13:31.672: E/NfcService(8667): No tag fallback activity found for Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
09-13 15:13:31.672: D/NativeNfcTag(8667): Tag lost, restarting polling loop
09-13 15:13:31.672: I/ActivityManager(1577): Starting: Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } from pid 8667
09-13 15:13:37.125: D/PowerManagerService(1577): mAutoBrightnessTask mPowerState : 3
```

09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672): NFC service dead - attempting to recover
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672): android.os.DeadObjectException
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.isEnabled(INfcAdapter.java:447)
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.isEnabled(NfcAdapter.java:402)
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at jp.co.aitia.siencemission.FeliCaReceivableActivity.isNfcAdapterEnabled(FeliCaReceivableActivity.java:112)
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at jp.co.aitia.siencemission.FeliCaReceivableActivity$1.run(FeliCaReceivableActivity.java:43)
09-17 14:52:11.556: E/NFC(24672):   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)